# ¿Cómo puedo escribir dos tuplas indefinidas en una función?

Tags: python, funcion

Quiero crear una función en Python que reciba dos listas y un número. No sé cuántos elementos tendrá la lista.

He intentado hacer:

```
def funcion(*tupla1 , *tupla2 , n)
```

Pero no reconoce la coma que separa tupla1 de tupla2 y sigue escribiendo todo como si fuera dentro de tupla1, por lo que al ejecutar, me dice que le faltan valores.

¿Cómo se puede arreglar esto?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Debes indicar el lenguaje en que estas trabajando. Para eso presiona [edit] y agrega la etiqueta respectiva

Comment: https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Answer (score 0):

El objetivo de `*args` es que la función pueda recibir un número mayor de argumentos. Python no permite que haya 2 parámetros así en una función.

Se me ocurre que si puedes hacer una función con parámetros normales.

```
def funcion(lista1, lista2, n)
```

También, aunque no sea la opción más legible, si hay alguna forma de determinar cuántos elementos corresponden a cada lista puedes hacer algo así:

```
def funcion(*args, n):
    lista1 = args[:n]
    lista2 = args[n:]

    ...

funcion(1, 2, 3, 4, n = 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def funcion(tupla1, tupla2, n):
    print(tupla1);
    print(tupla2);
    print(n);



x = [1, 2, 3];
y = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

funcion(x, y, 2);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].